# Image / file upload issue on civivolunteer public form

Tags: civivolunteer

I am just wondering if file uploading (image) is supported in CiviVolunteer as I am having an issue where attaching an image to a volunteer signup form is not being captured / displayed on the view contact details page.

Is this possibly a bug or just not supported by CiviVolunteer?

For clarity on what I have done so far and the results I am experiencing.

We want to add a file upload option on volunteer sign up page that allows the volunteer to add a picture of themself.

So I created a new custom field (file upload) and assigned it to a volunteer application form profile with expected results.
i.e: Field is displayed on public form and also available on the contact record.

However, once the form has been submitted and the new contact created the image is not available on the contact details page.

I assumed the image would be rendered next to the label or possibly a link to view elsewhere.

When editing the contact details from within Civi I am able to upload an image and then upon saving it is rendered on screen.
So it seems that the file upload is working but just not via the public form.

Tested with CiviCRM 5.13.5 and Master branch of Volunteer.

I have attached screenshots to detail what is going on.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

da_adamt, Welcome to CiviCRM SE. This seems to be bug in Civi Volunteer extension. I have just submitted a [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/pull/519) for this. Can you try applying patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/pull/519.patch)?

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Hi Pradeep.

This seems to have fixed the issue!
Image / file is now uploading as expected after applying your fix.

Thank you for help on this one, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the fix in the PR?
I could not reproduce the problem, but I made the mistake of grabbing an instance that is not up to date with civicrm core.
So, I gather this must be caused by a change in core for profile processing.

hmmm... I just noticed that without this patch, the profile submit button does change based on the presence of a file-upload field.

without a file-upload:

```
<input class="crm-form-submit default validate" accesskey="S" crm-icon="fa-check" name="_qf_Edit_next" value="Save" type="submit" id="_qf_Edit_next">
```

with a file-upload:

```
<input class="crm-form-submit default validate" accesskey="S" crm-icon="fa-check" name="_qf_Edit_upload" value="Save" type="submit" id="_qf_Edit_upload">
```

This seems similar to what your PR attempts to achieve?

So, I'm looking for more evidence that this is not an instance configuration problem.